# How to use db.subtract after time using glitch.com, discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Basically im trying to run this code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const db = require("quick.db");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
let user = message.member;

 let vic = db.get(`vic_${user.id}`);
    console.log("Activating auto start command!");

    let intro = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("You have dosed on vicodin and you are now immune to all shots")
    .setColor('#00cc00');
  let nopill = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("You do not own this drug")
  .addField("Error", "<:bluepill:713790607901982780> --- **You do not own any `Vicodin Pills`, please purchase off of the black market** --- <:bluepill:713790607901982780>")
  .setFooter("Must own first")
   let pill = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("You have already dosed")
  .addField("Error", "<:bluepill:713790607901982780> --- **You have already dosed on `Vicodin Pills`, please wait until the effect wear off to dose again** --- <:bluepill:713790607901982780>")
  .setFooter("Already dosed")
   if (args[0].startsWith("testing")) {
      if (vic === null) return  message.channel.send(nopill)
   } else if (args[0].startsWith("vicodin")) {

   if (vic === 0) return  message.channel.send(nopill)
 if (vic === 2) return message.channel.send(pill)


      message.channel.send(intro)

       db.set(`vic_${user.id}`, 2)
  console.log(`${user} just dosed vicodine`);
    setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`this is a test by zuc`)
          db.set(`vic_${user.id}`, 0)

            }, 1800000);
        }
    }
```

What it dose is when a user run the `Dose` command it makes them dose on the pill, im trying to make the pill/dose remove after a certain amount of time using  `db.subtract`, since im using glitch.com to do this, the setTimeout isnt doing what i want it to after that time.

Answer (score 1):

Change the timeout code to:

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
     console.log(`this is a test by zuc`)
      db.delete(`vic_${user.id}`);
      db.add(`vic_${user.id}`, 0);
    }, 1800000);
```